# Redirect local host mail to mailcow mail server ubuntu

Tags: postfix, email-server

I've installed mailcow dockerized on ubuntu 22.04 host. There is some instruction how to setup local mtu with postfix (sendmail is ubuntu default) https://docs.mailcow.email/post_installation/firststeps-local_mta/. Following this instruction I installed postfix and setup it, so now the command:

`echo test | mail -s "test message" root`

sends a test message, that can be read by root user using command `mail`.

Now I would like to make `mail` send emails not to local mailboxes but to the installed mailcow mailbox (in docker on the same host).

Normally I would have changed `/etc/aliases` and put there something like:
`root:myemail@mydomain`
and then `newaliases`

With current settings connection will be rejected. I've tried to play with hostname and destionation in main.cf but had no such user.

How should I setup the system now to receive local host mail in mailcow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use **ssmtp** for that. It could be installed with

```bash
apt install ssmtp
```

Then you need to update the config file `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```ini
# root is the receiving alias
root=myemail@mydomain.com

# This is required for ssmtp to send emails with authenticated smtp
mailhub=mail.yourmailcow.com:587
AuthUser=ubuntu-system@mydomain.com
AuthPass=your-mailcow-account-password
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

This should enable you to send emails from **ubuntu-system@mydomain.com** over your *mailcow* instance via authenticated *SMTP*. This would make sure, that the emails are sent correctly and are not catched by the *SPAM filter*.

Here is an [article](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205407478-Set-Up-SSMTP-for-Mail-Relay-to-AuthSMTP) that gives some additional information on how to use **ssmtp** for local mail relay.

Comment: Seems like it works. While I had to add hostname (that it determines) like a domain in mailcow. Than a catch-all alias for this domain with owner my recipient account. (Except creating a system acc to send emails). Without that it sent only to root. It sends service emails form root to smbd@host and not root. If I send from local user it sends from user@host to user@host. So I needed the catch-all alias for that. While it says smth about userids < 1000 in config comments